# grep question using backslash

Tags: grep, pattern-matching, ksh

I have the following file:

```
asdasd
asd
asd
incompatible:svcnotallowed:svc\:/network/bmb/clerver\:default
incompatible:svcnotallowed:svc\:/network1/bmb/clerver\:default
incompatible:svcnotallowed:svc\:/network2/bmb/clerver\:default
asdasd
asd
asd
as
```

And now suppose I have the two variables `v1="incompatible:svcnotallowed:"` and `v2="svc\:/network1/bmb/clerver\:default"`. 
I would like to search the entire file using v1 and v2. I know this is a problem caused due to the file having a'\' in it. I just dont know how to eliminate it. I have tried storing  v1 and v2 (both variable contents and grep usage) using single quotes, but in vain.

This is the series of commands I have tried :

```
grep "$v1$v2" file
grep '$v1$v2' file
```

I need this to work in **KSH**
please let me know the right way to use grep in this scenario.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep -F "$v1$v2" file` should do the trick -- with the `-F` option, it treats the pattern as a fixed string, so backslashes don't get interpreted as escapes or backreferences.

But `fgrep "$v1$v2" file` would probably be the most portable solution. As tomkaith13 notes in his comment, the `-F` option to `grep` isn't universally supported.  On Solaris, the default `grep` doesn't support `-F`, but the version in /usr/xpg4/bin does.

Comment: Got it ....:) I tried /usr/xpg4/bin/grep .... apparently the /usr/bin/grep does not support -F ... thank you

Comment: @tom:  Let me guess, Solaris? I think most other platforms these days would have GNU grep as the default.  Nice to know the xgp4 version also supports `-F`, though.  There's also `fgrep`, which is probably the most portable tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ksh, you can just use it to read the files

```
v1="incompatible:svcnotallowed:"
v2="svc\:/network1/bmb/clerver\:default"
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        "$v1$v2" ) echo "$line";;
    esac
done < file
```